# Replace values in Excel sheet using VBA and a reference table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with a column that contains numbers. I also have a reference table where each number corresponds to a word (for example 1=apple, 2=banana, etc).

I'd like to write a VBA code that utilizes the reference table to replace the numbers in the first table by the corresponding fruit.

I know this can be solved with regular Excel formulas, but it Needs to be VBA because it's part of a whole process that's within VBA.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom range named RNG_REFERENCES with 2 columns, first column is the number, second column is the replacement word. Something like this

```
1 apples
2 bananas
```

After this, i would do something like this:

```
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveCell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActiveCell.Value, Range("RNG_REFERENCES"), 2, False)
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
```

I tested with a column filled with numbers 1 to 4. It replaced the cells containing 1 with the word "apples" and cells containing 2 with the word "bananas"